# Cannot return a HTML Table after an Ajax Call

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have two php pages. The first page runs a Bootstrap Progress Bar as soon as the page starts loading. The second page creates a table by getting values from an api.

What I would like to do is get the html table on the first page after the second page generates the table. So, I started by writing an Ajax call from the first page that calls the second page

Ajax call

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'expensepage.php',
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
</script>
```

In order to test what data it returns, I used an alert. But for some reason it simply returns the code on the 2nd page, it doesn't return the table.

Here is my code
[Page 1](http://wardpeter.com/harvest_url/expense.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>

<title>Harvest Expense Report</title>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'expensepage.php',
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var progressBar = $('.progress-bar');
var percentVal = 0;


window.setInterval(function(){
    percentVal += 1;
    progressBar.css("width", percentVal+ '%').attr("aria-valuenow", percentVal+ '%').text(percentVal+ '%'); 

    if (percentVal == 100)
    {
       var link = document.getElementById('nav-ask');
link.style.display = 'none'
    }

}, 500); })
</script>


</head>

<body>



 <!--Progress Bar-->
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="progress"id="nav-ask">
                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%">
                        0%
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>





</body>

</html>
```

[Page 2](http://wardpeter.com/harvest_url/expensepage.php)

```
     <!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>

<title>Harvest Expense Report</title>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Choose a Month
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" select name="Dropdown_Month" id="month_dropdown" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <option class="dropdown-item" href="#" value="This">This Month</option>
    <option class="dropdown-item" href="#" value="Last">Last Month</option>
  </div>
  </select>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
 <h3><?php echo date('M Y'); ?></h3>
 <table class="table table-bordered">
 <thead>
     <tr>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Expense</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>

  <?php require_once( 'connection.php' );
  $result= $api->getUsers();
  $users=$result->data;



  $range= Harvest_Range::lastMonth();


  foreach($users as $key=>$value){

 $user_id=$value->get("id");
 $first_name=$value->get("first-name");
 $last_name=$value->get('last-name'); 

  $result_expenses=$api->getUserExpenses($user_id, $range);
 $expenses_data=$result_expenses->data;

 $total_cost=0;

foreach($expenses_data as $key=>$value){
if($value->get("is-locked")=="true"){
$total_cost=$total_cost+$value->get("total-cost");

}} 
 ?>
 <?php if($total_cost!=0){?>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <td> <?php echo $first_name; echo " ".$last_name; ?> </td>
 <td> $ <?php echo $total_cost; ?> </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 <?php }}?>

 </table>

 </body>

 </html>
```

I am not able to find a way to return the table after the AJAX GET Request is successful. I would like to display the table on the first page after the 2nd page finishes generating one.

Any Ideas on how this can be achieved?

Comment: AJAX is working as expected, it is returning everything which can be echoed out from the other page. If you want only the table create a PHP script which only has the table in it.

Comment: The only echo statements that I have on the 2nd page is the values in the table.

Comment: You are alerting what expensepage.php generates. If it is returning its contents as PHP code instead of executing, I would check that your webserver actually supports executing PHP. Once that has been confirmed working, if the issue persists we will need to see expensepage.php since your JS/jQuery looks fine.

Comment: I wasn't talking about the literal PHP `echo`, I was talking about the total output of the page requested.

Comment: @William_Wilson I have used this web server for generating php pages in the past. The code for expensepage.php is given on Page 2.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new php page and rewrote the statements to specifically output the rows of the table.

```
<?php 
// The purpose of this page is to feed the Ajax request from the home page. It would basically collect the values for the table.

 require_once( 'connection.php' );
  $result= $api->getUsers();
  $users=$result->data;



  $range= Harvest_Range::lastMonth();

echo "Test";
  foreach($users as $key=>$value){

 $user_id=$value->get("id");
 $first_name=$value->get("first-name");
 $last_name=$value->get('last-name'); 

  $result_expenses=$api->getUserExpenses($user_id, $range);
 $expenses_data=$result_expenses->data;

 $total_cost=0;

foreach($expenses_data as $key=>$value){
if($value->get("is-locked")=="true"){
$total_cost=$total_cost+$value->get("total-cost");

}} 
  if($total_cost!=0){

 echo "<tr> <td>  ". $first_name; echo " ".$last_name; 


echo "</td> <td> ".$total_cost; echo " </td> </tr>";
 }}


?>
```

Then on the 1st PHP Page, I created a structure of the table and added an ID called "display_rows" against the body of the table. I used AJAX to target that ID when the request is successful.

AJAX Code

```
   <script>
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'expensegeneratereport.php',
        success: function(data){
            $('#display_rows').html(data);
        }
    });
    </script>
```

HTML

```
<table class="table table-bordered"><div id="display_table">
 <thead>
     <tr>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Expense</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>

 <tbody id="display_rows">
 </tbody>

 </table>
```